# Making extern declarations out of the global declarations in C using emacs' query-replace-regexp

Tags: regular-expression, emacs

I have a hell lot of the following global declarations in a .c file:

```
fi_status_t ACLINFRA_CORE_OK = { { e_FI_STAT_MODULE_ACLINFRA, e_FI_STAT_ACLINFRA_SUBMOD_CORE, e_FI_STATUS_OK }, NULL };
fi_status_t ACLINFRA_CORE_ERR_GDFW_REG_FAILED = { { e_FI_STAT_MODULE_ACLINFRA, e_FI_STAT_ACLINFRA_SUBMOD_CORE, e_CORE_ERR_GDFW_REG_FAILED }, NULL };
fi_status_t ACLINFRA_CORE_ERR_DHAS_REG_FAILED = { { e_FI_STAT_MODULE_ACLINFRA, e_FI_STAT_ACLINFRA_SUBMOD_CORE, e_CORE_ERR_DHAS_REG_FAILED }, NULL };
fi_status_t ACLINFRA_CORE_ERR_GDFW_REQ_FAILED = { { e_FI_STAT_MODULE_ACLINFRA, e_FI_STAT_ACLINFRA_SUBMOD_CORE, e_CORE_ERR_GDFW_REQ_FAILED }, NULL };
```

Now, I have yanked and pasted them into a `.h` file.  But how do I use emacs to easily covert them into the equivalent `extern` declarations using `query-replace-regexp`?

The extern declaration would look like the following:

```
extern fi_status_t ACLINFRA_CORE_OK;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace: `^\(\w.*?\) *=.*`
by: `extern \1;`

Explanation: match lines beginning (`^`) with a word constituent (`\w`) followed by any number of characters other than newline (`.*?`) up to the first occurrence of zero or more spaces (`​ *`) followed by an equal sign and more characters other than a newline (`=.*`). The part of the line up to and excluding the optional spaces followed by the equal sign is placed in a group which the replacement text can use as `\1`.

If you have initializers that span multiple lines, you may want to remove lines that start with some whitespace, with `M-x flush-lines` on the regex `^\s-`.